# how to rename database in local disck to attach again in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have database in sql server in local disk ,I was renamed it to attach again but this message occer Cannot attach a database with the same name as an existing database

Answer (score 0):

Did you rename mdf /ldf file as well?

Thanks,